# CSMA/CD computer science clarification

Tags: networking

Im a CS student doing Networking and have a dilemma on the CSMA/CD, more specifically the explanation I have been given in class.

The exercise/problem is as follow: using CSMA/CD, station A starts transmitting at time 0, when A reaches time 8, B starts transmitting. Total time to travel from A to B is 10.
When A and B will know a collision happened?

After a bit of search, my understanding is as follow:
A is 8, B is 0 and starts. They both meet at time 9 where collision occurs. At collision time time 9 the signal is propagated in both direction informing A and B of collision:

therefore B is informed at time 2 ( 10 - 9 = 1, 1 in one direction + coming back 1 == 2)
A is informed at time 18 (time 9 at collision + 9 to travel back == 18)

Am I correct in my reasoning?

The explanation given was as follow:
A is informed at 18 because A was 8 + 10 to travel back
B is informed at 10 because it takes 10 to travel from B to A

I am a bit unsure if the explanation given makes sense (to me). Arent the frame discarded at collision and a higher signal because of the crash is propagated to both station in both directions ?

Edit: we are using Tanenbaum's book

Comment: Unfortunately, all :_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here. Also, you are learning about an extinct technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collision cannot be sensed when the signals actually start to overlap within the medium - there's simply no sensor at that point. Instead, a collision is sensed when the signals overlap *at the interface of a node*.

Accordingly, B's signal takes 10 ticks to reach A, so A detects the collision at 18 ticks. A's signal has already covered 8 from 10 ticks when B starts sending, so B senses the collision just 2 ticks later, at 10 ticks.

The times you find are correct, but it isn't really like a loud collision that happens within the medium and then propagates back to the senders (like a car crash that is heard a moment later). A collision doesn't cause anything in the medium. A collision really 'happens' when it is sensed by multiple signals overlapping at any node's interface. In reverse, a collision is sensed by each node at a different time, depending on its distance from the first signal overlap (in the same way that you've interpreted it).

The distinction becomes important when dealing with *late* collisions that cannot be sensed by all nodes due to segment length violations and the missing signal overlap at extreme locations - no overlap, no collision detection.

That said, you should note that CSMA/CD and half-duplex transmission is long obsolete. Modern Ethernet uses fully switched, full-duplex mode exclusively.

Comment: 1/2 just to clarify a bit to make sure I got it: 

because A is already in the way covered 8 + 2 remaining to reach B, then when A reaches B at 10, B is informed about the collision ?

and A is informed at 18 because the signal travelled 8 already at the moment when B started and it takes 10 for B to reach A, so 10 + 8 = 18

would this be correct then ? so its in line with my in class explanation

Comment: 2/2 I thought the signals when collide its something similar like you mentioned about car crash. So instead is at each end, at the nodes, not in the channel so to speak ?

Yes I understand CSMA/CD is obsolete, its just for CS lessons as an overview I presume

Comment: 1/2 When A's signal reaches B at 10 ticks, the currently transmitting B *detects* the collision and subsequently *transmits a jam signal*, informing all nodes of the collision. A transmits until 18 ticks when it starts detecting B's overlapping signal. B's jam signal reaches A at 20 ticks but A has already started transmitting a jam signal after 18 ticks.

Comment: 2/2 A collision does happen within the channel, but there's nobody detecting it until the overlapping signals reach a node (where they still need to overlap, hence the segment length limitations).

Comment: got it, thank you, appreciated. I can sleep better now